# asp.net mvc form values display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to asp.net mvc. Basically i'm from php programmer.  In my php file i can display what are all the values coming from html page or form using `echo $_POST;` or `print_r($_POST);` or `var_dump($_POST)`. But in asp.net how can i achieve this to check what are all the values are coming from UI Page to controller.

Comment: first, start to read tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at the `Request.Form` property:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var values = Request.Form;
    ...
}
```

You could put a breakpoint and analyze the values. Or simply use a javascript development toolbar in your browser (such as FireBug or Chrome Developer Toolbar) to see exactly what gets sent to the server.

But normally you are not supposed to directly access the raw values. In ASP.NET MVC there's a model binder which could instantiate some model based on the values sent to the server.

For example you could have the following model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take this model as parameter:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ... you could use the model properties here
}
```

and now you could invoke this controller action either wityh a GET request passing the parameters in the query string (`/someaction?age=10&firstname=foo&lastname=bar`) or using a POST and sending them in the body.

Comment: I just wanted to add this point to my answer that the proper way is to use model in action. :) And I now I see that you edited question further ... +1

Comment: Really thanks for your response and i could understand by this why we want use the viewmodel for my ui page. thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

You can check the raw data via `Request.Form`.

But this is not he spirit of the ASP.NET MVC. It is preferd that you expect a model into your controller. You have all type safety mapping already done by special module called model binder.

So unless you work on some special case, you just add a model to the controller action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
    //Handle SomeModel data further ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action which will accept the parameters from the UI page like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string param1, int param2)
{
    //Now you can access the values here
}
```

or make an action which will accept the model

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
     //Access the model here
}
```